# Problem setting up multiple 3D models using a url as source with ar.js and A-frame

Tags: html, ar.js

I'm just recently learning to code for A-frame projects. When trying to set up a scene with multiple targets in A-fram, the 3D model that was supposed to be displayed by one of them doesn´t appear. The model, like the marker, uses an URL as the original but only the latter works.

Separating the ar.js and A-frame proved that the problem was apparently on ar.js, however, I may be mistaken.

You can find my code in this link since it is giving me too much trouble to post here due to the URL in the code. The file's name is "Problem code":

https://github.com/BrandexGlobal/ARDuratex/tree/master

Comment: Please copy a code snippet you are asking about to the question. Most people will not bother going to your Github repository.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, you can use base64 data uris OR blobs for turning raw content into a viable url. This url *should* work in any place that any other url would work. I say *should* because I am not familiar with the framework that you are using (I'm anti-framework and pro-vanilla), so there is a slight chance that your framework might mess something up.

Because it appears as though you are new to Stackoverflow, I shall explain this checkmark here. After reading and reviewing my answer, if (and only if) you are thoroughly satisfied with the answer I have posted here, then you can reward me by clicking this checkmark to accept this answer as the best answer. If someone else posts a better answer, then click their checkmark. Clicking a checkmark is not permanent: if someone later on post a better answer, then you can click their checkmark and switch the best answer over to the new answer posted.

Example of plain ordinary image:

```js
(function(mainImage) {
    mainImage.title = mainImage.src;
})(document.getElementById("mainImage"));
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr5Kg.jpg" id="mainImage"/>
```

Example of using base64 data URI (notice how the url is the image itself). Also, see [Jpillora's base64 encoder](http://jpillora.com/base64-encoder/) and [this demo page](https://anonyco.github.io/BestBase64EncoderDecoder/demo.html).

```js
(function(mainImage) {
    mainImage.title = mainImage.src;
})(document.getElementById("mainImage"));
```

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" id="mainImage"/>
```

Example of using a Blob URI. Notice how the url is dynamically generated similar to a memory address pointer.

```js
(function(){
    var rawData = atob("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");
    var rawDataLength = rawData.length;
    var typedArrayView = new Uint8Array(rawDataLength);
    for (var i=0; i<rawDataLength; i=i+1|0)
        typedArrayView[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
    var img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
    img.src = img.title = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
        typedArrayView
    ], {type: "image/jpeg"}));
})();
```

Another example is that we can encode the image as a Base64 data URI, then use an XMLHttpRequest to HTTP-get the data URI's contents, but set the `returnType` property of the XMLHttpRequest to Blob so that we get a blob from the base64 data URI.

```js
(function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", document.getElementById("base64DataURIImage").src);
    xhr.onload = function(){
       var img=document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
       img.src = img.title = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
    }
    xhr.send();
})();
(function(mainImage) {
    mainImage.title = mainImage.src;
})(document.getElementById("base64DataURIImage"));
```

```html
As a base64 URI: <img id="base64DataURIImage" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
<br /><br />
Then turned into a blob:
```

#### Resources:

For base64 data URIs, see [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

For my own library for correctly encoding base64 URIs with high unicode characters, see [this Github repository](https://github.com/anonyco/BestBase64EncoderDecoder)

For blobs, see [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)